# Avoid showing first frame of video in UWP MediaPlayerElement and MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on an UWP app that shows a list of short videos to the user.  For this app, the user wants to start viewing the video somewhere in the middle of the video (not always the same), but be able to rewind to the beginning if needed.

The app is using the `MediaPlayerElement` and `MediaPlayer` using Windows Fall Creators Update (1709) and the latest UWP SDKs (6.0.6)

When I set a new source video file, it always seems to show the first frame of the video, regardless of how I try to set the position.

If I set the desired position before setting the source, the `MediaPlayerElement` goes to that position in the current video, then starts the new video at position 0.

```
_mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
_mediaPlayer.Source = playbackItem;
```

If I set the source to `null`, then set the desired position before setting the source, the `MediaPlayerElement` flashes black, which is jarring and not desirable.

```
_mediaPlayer.Source = null;
_mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
_mediaPlayer.Source = playbackItem;
```

If I set the position after setting the source, the `MediaPlayerElement` show the first frame before going to position of `10s`.

```
_mediaPlayer.Source = playbackItem;
_mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

If I set the position in any of the event callbacks that get triggered on changing the source, it still shows the first frame before showing the frame at `10s`.

I have also tried using the MediaPlaybackItem constructor that takes a `StartPosition`.  This starts the video at `10s`, but it interprets the `StartPosition` as now being `t=0s`, so you can't ever get to the video before the `StartPosition`.

Is there something I am missing?  Or a creative way to get right to the frame of video I want, without showing the frame at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on my device and in contrast to you I always get to see just the requested frame whatever I do so it seems it depends on the video source used somehow.

The `MediaPlayer` has a `SeekCompleted` method that fires only after the position change request finishes and video is ready for playback. You could hide the `MediaPlayerElement` completely and make it `Visible` only after this event fires.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I am missing? Or a creative way to get right to the frame of video I want, without showing the frame at the beginning of the file?

[`MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) will load the video first frame by default. For this feature, if you want to load another frame, you could use [`MediaClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing.mediaclip) to clip a snippet of the video in the `VideoPlayer` loaded event like following:

```
var videoFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("big_buck_bunny.mp4");

// Create a MediaClip from the video file and apply our video effect
MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);
clip.TrimTimeFromStart = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(17);
clip.TrimTimeFromEnd = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

// Create a MediaComposition object that will allow us to generate a stream source
MediaComposition compositor = new MediaComposition();
compositor.Clips.Add(clip);

// Set the stream source to the MediaElement control
this.VideoPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(compositor.GenerateMediaStreamSource());
this.VideoPlayer.AutoPlay = false;
```

And then when your click play button, you could modify media source manually in the `CurrentStateChanged` event handler.

```
private void VideoPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (this.VideoPlayer.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.Paused:

            break;

        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            if (!this.VideoPlayer.AutoPlay)
            {
                this.VideoPlayer.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///big_buck_bunny.mp4");
                this.VideoPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

For more you could refer [Media compositions and editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing).